# Is there a way to consecutively draw in Python turtle?

Tags: python, graphics, python-turtle

Is there a way to have a turtle drawing something and having the current coordinates of the turtle displayed on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [turtle.position() or turtle.pos()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=position#turtle.position) for getting the current coordinates of the turtle displayed on the screen.

A simple program to display the same:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
screen = turtle.Screen()

# Function to display the turtle's coordinates
def display_coordinates():
    x, y = t.pos()
    screen.title(f"Turtle Current Coordinate - X: {x}, Y: {y}")
    screen.ontimer(display_coordinates, 100)  

display_coordinates()

#Simple Sqaure
for _ in range(4):
    t.forward(100)
    t.right(90)

screen.exitonclick()
```